# Keyboard keys " and @ have suddenly become reversed on Kubuntu 21.10

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout, 21.10, ubuntu-studio

I've been using a Bluetooth keyboard for over a year on the same system (Ubuntu Studio-Kubuntu 21.10).

A few days ago, I noticed that the <kbd>"</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) and <kbd>@</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>) keys suddenly became reversed. I'm using UK English, so I tried adding US English, because it would be correct with that layout. The layout remained the same, except I was unable to type `£` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>), as expected. But removing the US layout changed nothing. I tried other UK layout variants and they were of no help.I soldiered on with the problem until suddenly the <kbd>4</kbd> key was outputting <kbd>2</kbd>.

I assumed a broken keyboard and have a brand new one now, similar model but updated version. In UK English I *still* have the swapped <kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd>, but now the <kbd>#</kbd> key produces `arg:3` in Konsole, blank everywhere else.

This is driving me insane, as these are my most used symbols in my daily work. Any pointers as to what I can do about it much appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 is not supported anymore. Please check if the error is present in a supported version of Ubuntu (20.04 LTS or 21.10).

Comment: I do apologise, it was a typo on my part I am on 21.10

Comment: I've now rolled back to a backup older than when the problem started. I still don't know the cause, but this has solved the issue. This can stay closed. Thanks for being there though! :-D

Comment: What backup are you referring to? Timeshift?

Comment: Yes, Timeshift. I can only assume some config file or other became corrupt somehow.